# Fix tidyquant tq_get returning NULL for currency trading pairs

Tags: r, tidyquant

If I execute the following command in r

```
exchange_rates <- tq_get("EUR/USD", get = "exchange.rates", from = "2018-04-01", to = "2023-04-30")
```

there are no error but the resulting variable is empty:

```
> exchange_rates
NULL
```

Is there anything wrong in the way I'm using tq_get? Pulling stock data works just fine.

Thank you for any thoughts or tips you can spare!

EDIT: thank you @AdroMine; `get = "exchange.rates"` is no longer a supported function of tq_get

Comment: check the documentation of `tq_get`, "exchange.rates" is not a valid option for `get` argument. The last couple of examples in the documentation show one possible way for fetching exchange rates.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you for pointing that out to me. Turns out some [old tutorials](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyquant/versions/0.1.0/topics/tq_get) let me astray